# Delphi - ADODataSet Subset

Tags: delphi, datagrid, drop-down-menu, tadodataset

I am building a form in Delphi that has a dropdown of Services and a grid of Add-Ons for the select service.  The data I am getting comes from an API and I am storing the data for the Services in an ADODataSet as follows:

```
ID (integer)
Name (string)
Description (string)
BasePrice (currency)
AddOns (array of AddOn, not currently stored in the ADODataSet)
```

I would like to have the grid populate with the AddOn data based on the selection from the dropdown (each Service has a different list of Add-Ons).  How do I store the AddOn information so that it can be related back to the Service info?  Do I need to create a second ADODataSet or is there a way to store it in the same ADODataSet as the Services?

The AddOns have the following fields:

```
ID (integer)
Name (string)
Description (string)
UnitPrice (currency)
Quantity (integer)
```

I am using Delphi 2005 and have Indy for Delphi.

**EDIT**

In digging around the Fields editor for Datasets I found that I can create a field of type 'DataSet'.  Would this allow me to tie the two together?  If so can someone explain how that is done?

I tried to do it by creating a second dataset (ADODataSetAddOns) and assigning the new dataset to the dataset field in the first dataset (ADODataSetServices.AddOns) but get the error message 'No matching ADO data type for Dataset', which I assume is referring to the AddOns field not finding a dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 datasets (master-detail) to show the relation between the Services and Addons and then using [`TClientDataset`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet) as memory dataset you can store the selections using the `Service Id`, `Addon Id` pair as Index, the structure of this client dataset can be created in runtime like this

```
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Clear;
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('IdService', ftInteger);
  ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('IdAddon ', ftInteger);
  //add morr fieldd here is you want 
  ClientDataSet1.IndexDefs.Add('Index1','IdService;IdAddon',[ixPrimary, ixUnique]);
  ClientDataSet1.IndexName:='Index1';
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
```

and finally when you need pass the data selected by the user to the service you can iterate over the ClientDataset just as any  TDataset.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was able to solve this using ClientDataSets for both the Services and Add-Ons and then making them a master/details.